# Join two distinct select resultsets

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two select statements that look like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) FROM PHONE_CALLS GROUP BY NAME, PHONE_NUMBER;

SELECT DISTINCT(NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) FROM MISSED_CALLS GROUP BY NAME, PHONE_NUMBER;
```

These are two separate tables.

I would like to join the result sets of each of these statements on the PHONE_CALLS phone_number so the result would look like

```
phone_calls.NAME phone_calls.PHONE_NUMBER missed_calls.NAME, missed_calls.PHONE_NUMBER
```

...if there was a match.. Is this possible? Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct pc.name, pc.phone_number, mc.name missed_name 
from phone_calls pc, missed_calls mc
where pc.phone_number = mc.phone_number
```

This will give you all phone numbers having both received and missed calls. If you also need those that have only received or missed calls, use

```
select distinct 
  pc.name, 
  coalesce(pc.phone_number,mc.phone_number) phone_number, 
  mc.name missed_name 
from phone_calls pc
full outer join missed_calls mc on pc.phone_number = mc.phone_number
```

instead.